# The exponential of the identity operator in a Banach space

Tags: banach-spaces, normed-spaces

> Let $X$ be a Banach space and $I \in L(X)$ be the identity operator. Determine the action of the operator $e^I$ on $X$.

Pretty stuck here, not sure exactly what it means by determine the action. Very little ideas with this question really

Answer (score 2):

A thought to get started: write a power series for $e^I$.  See anything simple to do?  If you don't like the idea of just jumping to a full series, start with a partial sum and see what comes out.

Comment: okay, but what exactly does the question mean when it says determine the action?

Comment: I'm guessing because that is not a specific term for me in the same sense as it would be if you said e.g. "find the derivative."  A function has a domain and an action, or rule of assignment.  So, find what $e^I \textit{ does}$.  Can you give a nice formula for $e^I x$?

Comment: perfect that clears it up a lot. ill try that out

Comment: got out that _e^I=e^x_ would that be correct?

Comment: Observe that $I^n = I$ for all powers and so formally $(\sum \frac{I^n}{n!})x = (\sum \frac{I}{n!})x = (I \sum\frac{1}{n!})x = ex$, multiplied not exponentiated.